# yum issue - error msg

Tags: configuration, yum

i am using oracle linux server 6.2.

yum does not work.

a manual wget was already used according to
https://blogs.oracle.com/OTNGarage/entry/how_to_subscribe_to_the
.

there is always something about dropbox.

```
yum update firefox
Loaded plugins: refresh-packagekit, security
http://linux.dropbox.com/fedora/6Server/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404"
Trying other mirror.
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: Dropbox. Please verify its path and try again
```

does anybody know a workaround?

Answer (score 2):

The Dropbox repository doesn't seem to exist. Remove it from your `yum` configuration, and then contact Dropbox if you really want it.